# Unsupported format of git

Tags: git, android-studio

I keep getting an error message when trying to test my git executable in Android Studio. Can someone offer any advice?

I'm running Android Studio 2.2.2 on Windows 10 64-bit. I downloaded and successfully installed Git-2.10.1-64-bit. I have an account with Github. Git is installed on my secondary hard drive and not on C:.

The steps I take are:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click Configure
3. Click Settings
4. Click Git
5. Click Test
   Then a window opens with this message:

> Unsupported format of git --version output: [0x7FFD70F970E3] ANOMALY:
>   use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64) git version
>   2.10.1.windows.1 [0x7FFD70F970E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)

Answer (score 0):

I found it is caused by TrendMicro anti-virus program. If you also installed the TrendMicro  antivirus program . Try to unload it. and the GIT function is back again.

Comment: I tried disabling TrendMicro and the same problem happened. I also tried reinstalling both Git and Android Studio and the problem still persists.

Comment: disablling is not enough. you need "shut down" it. and I found that Trend Micro have a patch.

Comment: if you use office scan here is the patch.

Comment: http://downloadcenter.trendmicro.com/index.php?clk=tbl&clkval=4554&regs=NABU&lang_loc=1

Comment: if you use the PC-Cillin, pls upgrade to version 2017. it works for me.